# Появление определенного блока при нажатии на другие блоки, как сократить код?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Есть три блока, при нажатии на которые появляется определенный блок. Как можно сократить этот код?

```js
var pbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryP');
var works = document.getElementsByClassName('work__wrapper');
pbtn[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < works.length; i++) {
    works[i].classList.remove('displayFlex');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    works[0].classList.add('displayFlex');
  }, 100);
})

pbtn[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < works.length; i++) {
    works[i].classList.remove('displayFlex');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    works[1].classList.add('displayFlex');
  }, 100);
})

pbtn[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < works.length; i++) {
    works[i].classList.remove('displayFlex');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    works[2].classList.add('displayFlex');
  }, 100);
})
```

```css
.categoryP {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.category__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.work__wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.work__wrapper:nth-child(1) {
  background: pink;
}

.work__wrapper:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.work__wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  background: purple;
}

.displayFlex {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class="category__wrapper">
  <div class="categoryP">1</div>
  <div class="categoryP">2</div>
  <div class="categoryP">3</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="work__wrapper displayFlex"></div>
  <div class="work__wrapper"></div>
  <div class="work__wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот сам код -> ???

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ineye/pen/mNPgPW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как минимум так:

```js
var pbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryP');
var works = document.getElementsByClassName('work__wrapper');

[...pbtn].forEach((el, index) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    [...works].forEach((el) => el.classList.remove('displayFlex'));
    
    setTimeout(() => works[index].classList.add('displayFlex'), 100);
  });
});
```

```css
.categoryP {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.category__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.work__wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.work__wrapper:nth-child(1) {
  background: pink;
}

.work__wrapper:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.work__wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  background: purple;
}

.displayFlex {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class="category__wrapper">
  <div class="categoryP">1</div>
  <div class="categoryP">2</div>
  <div class="categoryP">3</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="work__wrapper displayFlex"></div>
  <div class="work__wrapper"></div>
  <div class="work__wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо дядька. Дай пожалуйста свой контакт. Или просто напиши мне на почту. illya.landar@gmail.com